# How to correctly capture HTML table cell (td) value on `focus in` using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

In my HTML table user has to fill information depending on certain parameters. The table rows may be added by the user as needed at runtime.

I am trying to capture such info (as filled in by the user) for later manipulation. To do that I am using the following:

```
$(function() {
    var focusedLegStart;
    var valLegStart;

    focusedLegStart  = 'id_rtelistitems_set-0-leg_start'; // Value updated manually for the first row

    $('#' + focusedLegStart).focusin(function() {
        // console.log('Focused on fld: ' + focusedLegStart);
        valLegStart = $('#'+ focusedLegStart).val();
        console.log('Value in Focused fld: ' + focusedLegStart + ' is ' + valLegStart);
    });
});
```

The *row number* in the variable `focusedLegStart` will be updated at runtime (based on the row we have **focus in**).

However, to test the situation when I am **manually** updating the row number from **0** to **1** in variable **focusedLegStart** and so on, the code fails to reproduce the result as with the first row (row number **0**).

**Question** is: How do I correctly capture field value on `focus in`?

### Edit

**At page load**, the number of rows in the table is **1 (row index 0)**.

Answer (score 0):

the tab `td` not trigger focus event by default.

but u can add `tabindex` attribute in td tag like :

`<td tabindex="1">`

then focus will be work for it , and it accepts an integer as a value, with different results depending on the integer's value, access [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) for the detail info :)

Comment: read the question again. tabindex?? what... is... it... going... to... do??? :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have inputs in your table. How about adding an on change event on the inputs? They will still be captured on run time and only when the change occurs, either:

```
<input onchange="myFunction()"> <!-- on every input -->
```

Or:

```
$("input").change(function(){
  // code
});
```

You can also pass parameters to the functions to narrow down what you're capturing:

```
<input onchange="myFunction(this)"> <!-- on every input -->
// JS
myFunction(el){
    console.log(el);
}
```

If some of the values are not changed by the user then you know to use the defaults in case you need to process all the inputs, or you can get the values programatically.

Comment: The value in the field (input) in question is intended to be **captured** on `focusin` in it. Not `.on('change',...)`.

Comment: works the same way > `<input type="text" onfocusin="myFunction(this)">`

Comment: `form.addEventListener('focusin', (event) => {
  code   
});`

Comment: OK. What I am going to do is modify my code and come back. Thanks.